# How do I iterate through 2 matrices and do calculations to specific elements? [Matlab]

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, for-loop, matrix

[Matlab] I have two matrices, A2 and B2. I want to go through each element of both arrays and do a calculation with the values from each array, output them into a new array, and then display the results.

The values of these arrays are currently in int format. I must change the output array to a float data type as well.

EXAMPLE:
I want to get element A2(50,101) and I want to get element B2(50, 101) then I want to use the values in that cell to do this calculation: (B2-A2)/(B2+A2). Then output those results to cell C2(50, 101).

```
% Clear Memory
clear;
% Load Landsat Bands
A1 = imread('p074r073_7t20010204_z60_nn30.tif'); % Red - Band 3
B1 = imread('p074r073_7t20010204_z60_nn40.tif'); % IR - Band 4
C1 = imread('p074r073_7t20010204_z60_nn20.tif'); % Green - Band 2
% Subset Fragment
xsize = 600; % Length in x
ysize = 600; % Length in y
A2 = imcrop(A1, [1800 1300 600 600]);
B2 = imcrop(B1, [1800 1300 600 600]);
C2 = imcrop(C1, [1800 1300 600 600]);
% False Color Image
RGBimage = cat(3, B2, A2, C2);
figure(1); imshow(RGBimage,[]); title('False Color Composite Image') % Shows Images
% NDVI Calculations
for a = 1:xsize
    RED = A2(a+1,:);
    for b = 1:xsize
        NIR = B2(b+1,:);
        NDVI = (NIR-RED)./(NIR + RED);
    end
end
figure(2);imshow(NDVI);
```

This currently gives me this image where as it is supposed to be a full image:

[image: NDVi Result]

Example calcs

A2:

3 4 5

5 6 7

8 9 1

---

B2:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

---

A2(2,3) & B2(2,3)

C2(2,3) = (6-7)/(6+7)

Comment: It's unclear on what exactly you're doing in your code.  Note that `NDVI` is going to be a 1D vector at each iteration of your inner loop, which is why you see one elongated black line when you show the image.  Are you trying to do a pixel-wise calculation?  In that case, you can avoid using any loops.  My point is that the explanation you provide and what your code is doing do not match.  Specifically, you reference `A1` in your question, but there is no such variable defined in your code.  Can you please show some example calculations with a small sized input?

Comment: @rayryeng I added the rest of my code. Sorry about that. What I have done is read 3 bands of an image into my program (Am only using 2 of them for calculations). With those pixel values (0-255) I want to do the NDVI calculation. This will give me a float data type which I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the NDVI, or the Normalized Difference Vegetation Index, you need the red and near-infrared channels from your data, which you already have.  These are stored in `A2` and `B2`.  You now want to compute the NDVI for each pixel in the image.  In this case, your loops aren't entirely correct.  At each iteration of your loop, you want to access only one pixel at a time, compute the NDVI then store this in the same location in the output image.

You don't have an output image set up, so you should probably deal with that first.  Once you do that, you'll have to specifically access each location for the input images, do the NDVI calculation then store that result in the same location in the output image.

Therefore, first create the output image which we'll call `NDVI`, then modify your `for` loops to be like this.  Note that the inner loop should be `ysize` instead of `xsize`:

```
A2 = double(A2);
B2 = double(B2);
NDVI = zeros(size(A2)); % Allocate image to be the same size as an input image
for a = 1:xsize
    for b = 1:ysize
        RED = A2(a,b); % Access the red pixel at location (a,b)
        NIR = B2(a,b); % Access the near-infrared pixel at location (a,b)
        NDVI(a,b) = (NIR-RED)./(NIR + RED); % Compute NDVI and store in the output location (a,b)
    end
end
figure; imshow(NDVI, []);
```

Note that `B2` and `A2` may be integer types to begin with, so we cast to `double` to ensure that the precision is floating-point prior to the calculations.  For each location `(a,b)`, access the right values in the red and near-infrared images, calculate the NDVI and store it in the right output location.  It's also prudent that you normalize the display so that the lowest value gets mapped to black or 0 and the highest value gets mapped to white or 1.  Negative values will saturate to 0 and values larger than 1 get saturated to white.

However, MATLAB is very powerful at vectorization.  What I mean to say is that you can compute the NDVI using one line of code where you can exploit the arithmetic operators to work on multiple points of data, rather than a single point of data looping through each element in the arrays.

Therefore, your loops can be replaced with:

```
A2 = double(A2);
B2 = double(B2);
NDVI = (B2 - A2) ./ (B2 + A2);
figure;
imshow(NDVI, []);
```

As you can see, this matches your expression you've written above and this is much simpler to digest and communicates quite clearly what you want to accomplish.  Also note that we don't need to pre-allocate the output array before doing the calculations.  This is done on the fly.